# Touch Screen System: Can we run our normal dot net application on touch screen computer system without any change

Tags: system, screen, touch

I have an application that is build in dot net 3.5. Basically it's a web application (asp.net and flash). Is this application need any modification while opening on Touch Screen Computer System.
I mean to say who will manage interaction with an application. Is application required any change or system will manage it self.

Thanks in advance.
Vinay Pandey

Answer (score 0):

As long as the operating system where the touch screen is installed supports touch input, you're good - no modifications needed for the web application. In fact, you can't directly manage touch-screen capabilities from your web application - it's tied to the OS and hardware.

Comment: Thanks, means no need to change the application at all. OS and hardware will handle the scenario.

Comment: Thanks, means no need to change the application at all. OS and hardware will handle the scenario. –

Comment: Hi, I want to test my application in touch screen environment. My application is a web site build in asp.net(.net framework 3.5) and flash. I want to test my application with the simulator with Windows XP/Vista/7.

Please let me know is there any simulator released my Microsoft or any third party where I can test my application.